# NGINX + NodeJS Performance Issues

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, node.js

I have one server running a Docker + NodeJS application and a load balancer running nginx. Before upgrading to two servers, I wanted to attempt to replicate traffic statistics for the load balancer and the existing server.

(Both machines are $5 instances at Digital Ocean)

When I run loader.io against the server directly, I was impressed that it could sustain up to 2000 requests per second for a 1 minute test.

However when I use loader.io against nginx, proxying to the other server, it simple gives up around 300 requests per second.

Since the one machine seems to be able to handle the load, I am unsure of what the issue is. I would assume it is my nginx.conf but I could use some pointers on optimizing it.

nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/MkX8P4eh